# Zend Session Identity losing object parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-auth

I have a strange problem I can't seem to track down. 
I have a custom class ("Person") extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract that represents a user.
Among other things, this class has custom variables that are set in the init() method, for instance:

```
class Person extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
        protected $_cdata = array(); // non-db-table data gets put here through __set()

        public function init()
        {
           $this->fullName = $this->firstName." ".$this->lastName; // this is saved to $this->_cdata['fullName']
        }
```

Upon login, I store an object of this class as Zend Auth Identity:

```
$r = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
if($r->isValid())
{
  $user = $db->getUserByEmail($email); // Retrieves an object of class "Person"
  $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
}
```

Now, if I call Auth Identity in the same action request as the login, it will work alright:

```
echo $user->fullName; // Will print "John Smith" or whatever it is
```

However, when I call another action, and call Auth Identity, I lose whatever I have stored in "_cdata" array:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if($auth->hasIdentity() {
   $user = $auth->getIdentity();
   echo $user->fullName; // Prints nothing...$_cdata['fullName'] does not exist.
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why that's happening is because `Zend_Auth` identity data gets serialized (and deserialized) between requests.

Which leads us to a closer look onto `__sleep` method of `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` class, which is the one that gets called once `$user` object is serialized.

```
public function __sleep()
{
    return array('_tableClass', '_primary', '_data', '_cleanData', '_readOnly' ,'_modifiedFields');
}
```

What you need to do is to override this method in your `Person` class, so that it includes `$_cdata` array as well. Then this property will be serialized and available in the next HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have got there on my own.

Comment: Yeah, I can clearly remember being stuck with this same issue for hours. Happy coding!